# st_simplify dTolerence with decimal degree

Tags: r, r-sf

I'm trying to reduce the size of `sf` object by applying `st_simplify`. CRS is 4267 and try to play around with the right level of `dTolerance`. I understand that the unit of `dTolerance` has to be that of the CRS, so I started with 0.1, but I constantly getting this error message.

```
test <- st_read("comm_sf.shp") %>%
+   st_simplify(preserveTopology = T,
+               dTolerance = 0.1)
Simple feature collection with 11321 features and 21 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -124.4375 ymin: 24.5441 xmax: -66.94983 ymax: 49.00249
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
Warning message:
In st_simplify.sfc(st_geometry(x), preserveTopology, dTolerance) :
  st_simplify does not correctly simplify longitude/latitude data, dTolerance needs to be in decimal degrees
```

I play around with both setting `dTolerance = 1000` (in case it's in meters) and `dTolerance = 0.1` (in case it's in long/lat), but I get the same error message. This happens with CRS = 4267 as well. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well its a warning rather than an error. But in general you should do Douglas-Peucker on a projected coordinate system - because it uses a distance as a buffer, whereas the actual size of a unit of longitude varies with latitude. Note that the unit used by st_simplify tolerance will always be in the same as the map units.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(sf)
library(maptools)

states = st_as_sf(maps::map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
states_simple = st_simplify(states)
##Warning message:
##  In st_simplify.sfc(st_geometry(x), preserveTopology, dTolerance) :
##  st_simplify does not correctly simplify longitude/latitude data, dTolerance needs to be in decimal degrees
```

But if we transform to a projected coordinate system first, then no warning:

```
states = st_transform(states, 54032) #azimuthal equidistant
states_simple = st_simplify(states)
```

You can always go back to WGS84 lat-long after the simplification

```
 states = st_transform(states, 4326)
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the answer! Can I ask a follow-up question? What exactly "the actual size of a unit of longitude varies with latitude" this phrase means?

Comment: If you look at a globe you will see that a line around the earth at constant latitude (called a 'parallel') Is a different size, depending how close to the poles or the equator you are.  E.g. the equator is much longer than the arctic circle.  But both go 360 degrees around the earth's axis.  Therefore, a degree of longitude in the arctic is a shorter distance than a degree of longitude at the equator